# using sortable widget with inline kendo grid

Tags: razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using inline editor in my kendo grid razor.I want to add kendo sortable widget for reordering rows in grid. But whenever i am appending sortable in my code one of my fields in the grid looses its control i.e. whenever i click on that column for adding data my textbox appears at once and whenever i enter the data and move to another column then the value entered is gone. When i remove the sortable code then the data is displayed perfectly. Please tell me a solution to it.

My code is :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMVC5.Models.Product>()    
    .Name("Grid")    
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Order).Width(60);   
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Width(140);
    })
.ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Create().Text("Add New Route Part"))
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()       
        .Batch(true)  
        .ServerOperation(false)                
        .Model(model => {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
        })
        .Read("Read", "Home")
        .Update("Update", "Home")
        .Sort(s => s.Add(m => m.Order))
    )
)

@(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
    .For("#Grid")
    .Filter("table > tbody > tr")
    .Cursor("move")
    .HintHandler("noHint")
    .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
    .ContainerSelector("#Grid tbody")
    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody like me is running into the same problem, you have to change the sortable filter to `.Filter("table >tbody >tr:not(.k-grid-edit-row)")`.

More informations about: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/interactivity/sortable/integration/grid